# add prefix to all website content img src

Tags: html, css, ruby, jekyll, jekyll-extensions

I recently begin to use cdn to speed up images.  The origin img src is something like `/images/effect.png` , I want to add a prefix to all article content image src.

```
div.entry-content p > img {
    content:attr(src,'http://cdn.example.com'+src)
}
```

I know that the best solution is to change all articles. Another solution is to use javascript to do it(but it seems still to download origin img).

<del>I just want to use pure css.</del>

(update 1)
I'm using jekyll as backend. Because I use markdownpad to write articles, it can only preview img with `![](/images/effect.png)` , so I donnot want to use `{% img url %}`.

Can anyone help me add img src a prefix?

Answer (score 1):

CSS absolutely can't do this.  Maybe `<base>` would do it, but that would affect your intrasite links and JS/CSS URLs as well.

You have to change them all manually.  Sorry.  Hope you've got a template engine on your backend.

Comment: I use jekyll. I use markdownpad to write articles, I can preview img with `![](/images/effect.png)`. But Jekyll with kramdown cannot add some post_process filter to the image.

Comment: Jekyll can use {% img url %} tags, but it's not markdown. So markdownpad cannot preview it.

Comment: are you sure jekyll can't handle this for you?  i don't know too much about it but i thought it was pretty flexible.

Comment: Agree there is no automatic way to do it, this is a good related article: http://brettterpstra.com/2014/02/21/a-jekyll-cdn-with-cloudfront/